# Was the evidence planted?

Tags: gattaca

By the end of the film, one of the detectives finally finds evidence pointing at the killer of the mission director. He picks a swab which lays by the victims body in the morgue. But was the evidence planted there? It's a bit unusual they considered an evidence this late into the investigation and the placement of the swab, laying next to the body makes little sense as well.

> Did Vincent's brother plant them there for the other detective to find?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All signs point to the evidence simply having been mislaid by a technician. Note that it's been *carefully labeled* as coming from the right ocular cavity.

[image]

and in an earlier scene you see them collecting samples and putting them into a jar **right next to the Mission Director's head** (in what can only be described as a *flagrant breach* of forensic science methodology).

[image]

Additionally, the Director openly confessed to his crimes so there isn't much scope for the evidence having been planted.

---

You may wish to note that in the [original screenplay](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Gattaca.html), immediately after the launch was given final confirmation and couldn't be cancelled, the Director *came forward* to the police with a full confession and handed over his clothing, covered in blood and gore.

> INT.  CRIME LABORATORY.  DAY.
>
> An EXTREME CLOSE UP of dried blood - brittle and cracking - on a pair
>   of soiled latex gloves.  A latex head mask, suit of clothes and shoe
>   covers are similarly caked.  The INVESTIGATOR and DETECTIVE HUGO watch
>   as a white-coated FORENSIC TECHNICIAN feeds a minute sample of the
>   dried blood into an analyzer.
>
> The INVESTIGATOR wanders over to a one-way glass window through which
>   he can observe DIRECTOR JOSEF, sitting numb but strangely serene in an
>   interrogation room.  The Investigator, in a state of shock himself,
>   cannot yet bring himself to believe what is plainly obvious.